# Пунктирная линия, которая подстраивается под контент

Tags: html, css3

Требуется реализовать пунктирную линию между двумя элементами, но не просто одного размера, а чтобы она подстраивалась под контент. Может кто дать идею по реализации данной фичи?)
Пример:

```
Доставлено -------- время  
В пути ------------ время 
Error ------------- время
В статусе готовки - время
```

Статусы перебираются через .map так что вариацию через каждый отдельный li отпадает.

Текущий код:

```
<ul>
  {elements.status.map((element, index) => (
  <li key={index}>
    <p>{element.status}</p>
    <br /> // вот тут должна быть линия
    <p>{formatDate(element.createdAt)}</p>
  </li>
  ))}
</ul>
```

Comment: Используйте JavaScript метод для строк `padEnd` и будет вам счастье

Comment: @ΝNL993 можете подробнее рассказать об этом свойстве? Не пойму, как оно поможет мне. Ему я могу указать количество повторений символа "-", но опять же - это будет фиксированное значение

Answer (score 0):

```css
li {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  column-gap: 5px;
}
p:first-child {
  white-space: nowrap;
}
span {
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
}
ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 10px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  min-width: 250px;
  width: 250px;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>
    <p>Доступно </p>
    <span>---------------------------------------------------------------</span>
    <p> 100</p>
  </li>
  <li>
    <p>На складе </p>
    <span>---------------------------------------------------------------</span>
    <p> 1.000</p>
  </li>
  <li>
    <p>Отсутствует на складе </p>
    <span>---------------------------------------------------------------</span>
    <p> 100</p>
  </li>
</ul>
```